# Is there a simpler lodash technique to search array parameter?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm only looking for lodash based solution. I cannot use javascript 6 features.

The below code works. It finds the "record" that contains the requested string in the circleStoreId array. I feel like there should be a simpler, more lo-dashy way to achieve this. Am I missing a better solution?

```
var RECORDS = [
    {
        circleStoreId: [
            'AKWX3MWZ0FFT6',    //  WS Herb Counter
            'C9VKT4W6GQNBM',    //  WS Bar
            'KPN3W7SHAH1P6'     //  WS Front Counter
            ],
        acmeLocationIId: 3,
        channelIId: 2
    },
    {
        circleStoreId: [
            '0ZK8FZHPD5G71',    //  SK Herb Counter
            '6VCZ7NNAF2VWW'     //  SK Bar
            ],
        acmeLocationIId: 4,
        channelIId: 1
    }
    //  Ready for the next retail location to be added...
];

var f = _.find(RECORDS, function(r) {
    return _.indexOf(r.circleStoreId, '6VCZ7NNAF2VWW') > -1;
});

console.log(f)
```

The console will output

> {circleStoreId: Array(2), acmeLocationIId: 4, channelIId: 1}

Comment: Native js (es2016) `RECORDS.find(r => r.circleStoreId.includes('6VCZ7NNAF2VWW'))`

Comment: @zerkms - good one. I failed to mention that 6th addition wasn't on option, sorry about that. Question has been updated.

Comment: overthinking it probably.

Comment: Overthinking what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe using `includes` instead of `indexOf`. But it does not improve that much.

```
var f = _.find(RECORDS, function(r) {
    return _.includes(r.circleStoreId, '6VCZ7NNAF2VWW'));
});

console.log(f)
```

Comment: That's an improvement, for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Using ES6 [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) :

```js
var RECORDS = [
    {
        circleStoreId: [
            'AKWX3MWZ0FFT6',    //  WS Herb Counter
            'C9VKT4W6GQNBM',    //  WS Bar
            'KPN3W7SHAH1P6'     //  WS Front Counter
            ],
        acmeLocationIId: 3,
        channelIId: 2
    },
    {
        circleStoreId: [
            '0ZK8FZHPD5G71',    //  SK Herb Counter
            '6VCZ7NNAF2VWW'     //  SK Bar
            ],
        acmeLocationIId: 4,
        channelIId: 1
    }
    //  Ready for the next retail location to be added...
];

var f = RECORDS.find( r => r.circleStoreId.includes('6VCZ7NNAF2VWW'))

console.log(f)
```